# Detect image URL and wrap in IMG tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Trying to hack away at a Wordpress installation to add a little more user-friendliness in the comment section of a specific plugin.

**Given three cases:**

**1**

```
This is a sentence and image on a newline
http://imgur.com/image.gif
```

**2**

```
This is a sentence http://imgur.com/image.gif
```

**3**

```
This is a sentence and an image with IMG tags entered by user already
<img src="This is a sentence http://imgur.com/image.gif" alt="" />
```

---

When displaying these three types of comments from a user, I'd like to have PHP detect the 1st case and 1st case only - an image url on a newline (a URL that ends in common image extensions) and simply wrap it in `<img>` tags when displaying.

The part I'm having trouble with, given the string of the comment, how does PHP accurate detect an image link like that?

I feel like this could be accomplished with regex but I've never been terribly skilled with it? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: Can you clarify what makes up that specific URL you want to replace? Is it the `imgur.com` domain, or ending that line with `.gif` (or `.jpg`)?

Comment: @NicoHaase i just used imgur as an example, basically whatever would pass basic classification of a URL pointing at an image file (ends in .gif/jpg/png and maybe starts with http for example?)

Comment: @user3783243 wow that's actually a good starting point, thanks, though I was hoping to have it where it only detects an bothers adding IMG tags only if the URL is alone on it's own newline (also I see that example would detect, for example, http://google.com and wrap it in IMG tags as well) - I might be able to hack away at it myself tho

Comment: @user3783243 thanks, that last one is basically perfect, I had hacked that together myself before I noticed you actually commented it, thanks

Comment: Great, I've moved that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex will will look at the start of each line (`(?m)^`), any amount of horizontal whitespace (`\h*`) (spaces or tabs), and then the HTTP protocol (`https?://`). After the protocol it takes any non-space characters (`\S+?`) (because URLs can't have spaces) until the allowed extension (`jpe?g|gif|png|tiff|svg`).

```
(?m)^\h*(https?://?\S+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|tiff|svg))
```

Replace with:

```
<img src="$1" />
```

https://regex101.com/r/OXvsBl/3/